# A graph with maximum vertex degree $3$ can be divided into $2$ groups with simple structure

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

I am struggling with the following problem for a while.

If $G=(V, E)$ is a graph with maximum vertex degree $3$, then the vertex set $V$ can be divided into $2$ groups in such way that every vertex in each group has at most one neighbor in that group.

If $G$ has a pendant, then we can delete it and proceed by induction on the number of edges.
If there exist a pair of adjacent vertices $x, y$, with degree $2$, then deleting the edge {$x, y$} and induction may work. I have thought about longest path, longest vertex-disjoint cycle without getting any progress.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a vertex partition $A,B$ of $V$, and a vertex $v\in V$,
let $t(v)$ be the "cross-degree" of $v$, i.e. the number of neighbours
of $v$ in the other partition.

Let $A,B$ be a partition of the vertices of $G$, that maximizes $\sum_v t(v)$.
Suppose $v\in A$ has 2 neighbours in $A$, say $x$ and $y$, and (at most) one neighbour, $z$ in $B$.
Then moving $v$ to the other partition increases $t(x)$ and $t(y)$ by one,
decreases $t(z)$ (if $z$ exists) by one and increases $t(v)$ by (at least) 1.

This total increase of at least 2 contradicts our choice of the partition $A,B$,
so our assumption that $v$ has 2 neighbours in $A$ is wrong.
We conclude that every vertex of $A$ has at most 1 neighbour in $A$ and similarly for $B$.